# joomla hash that will work on my site?

Tags: php, joomla, hash

I'm just a beginner in joomla and I was trying to create a password hash to make an account from phpmyadmin (manually) and every thing went cool but when I tried to login it gave me (wrong password).

I'm using this code to get the password hash:

```
require("includes/defines.php");
require("includes/framework.php");
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($_POST["password"], $salt);
$password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

I think the problem is with that random value but how to fix it?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use any md5 encoder to encode your password with md5 (something like http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/) and replace user password with md5 hash. It always works for me.

But if you're making account manually, don't forget about relation and ACL tables. I'd suggest to replace password of existing joomla account, then login to back-end and create a new account.

This is how i would do it:
1. Find admin user in PhpMyAdmin and copy it's original hash somewhere.
2. Replace it with your new generated md5(password)
3. Login and create your own admin account
4. Return the original value of account password with PhpMyAdmin